# Javascript validation for .net dropdownlistbox control?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, unobtrusive-javascript

I have 3 dropdownlistbox..

1. country
2. state
3. cities

When I am selecting country name, as per its state name and city name change. In that if I am
changing state name then city name is changed in dropdownlist box.

Using only Javascript not postback of .net control.

I have faced so much problem by making array of country, states and cities.

I thought if I have list of names of countries, states and cities than how can I maintain
array of it?

So help me to get out of it, and give me good Javascript to get out from this problem?

Comment: what exactly is the problem/question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var countries = [
   {
       name:'USA',
       states:[
            {
                name:'New York',
                cities:['New York','Albany',...,'Some place']
            },
            {
                name:'Florida',
                cities:['Miami','Ft Loterdale']
            }
       ]
   },
   {
        name:'Canada' ...
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not this instead:

```
data: { 
  "United States" : {
    "California" : ["San Francisco","San Jose","Watsonville"],
    "Alaska" : ["Anchorage","Juneau"]
  },
  "Canada" : {
    "Alberta" : ["Calgary","another town"]
  }
}
```

This makes it territory neutral, not needing names like "state", "city", "province", etc. Iterate through the object by using

```
for(var key in data) { var country = data[key]; var state = data[key][territory] }
```

or use any number of object traversing methods.